# PHP: JSON not working when using urldecode and mcrypt

Tags: php, json

When I run json code through json_decode it works fine, but when I encrypt with mcrypt and encode with urlencode then decode and decrypt, it doesn't work.

Does anyone know what's wrong?

The decrypted json looks exactly like the json before being encrypted.

**My code:**

```
<?
    $json = '{"entry1":{"name":"bob","age":"15"},"entry2":{"name":"bill","age":"50"}}';

    $iv_size = mcrypt_get_iv_size(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_256, MCRYPT_MODE_ECB);
    $iv = mcrypt_create_iv($iv_size, MCRYPT_RAND);
    $key = "abcdefghijkl";
    $encrypted = mcrypt_encrypt(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_256, $key, $json, MCRYPT_MODE_ECB, $iv);
    $urlencoded = urlencode($encrypted);
    $urldecoded = urldecode($urlencoded);
    $decrypted = mcrypt_decrypt(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_256, $key, $urldecoded, MCRYPT_MODE_ECB, $iv);

    // json and decrypted json comparison
    echo "<h3>JSON & Decrypted JSON look the same:</h3>";
    echo $json . " // json<br>";
    echo $decrypted . " // decrypted json<br>"; 

    // json - works!
    echo "<h3>JSON works:</h3>";
    $data = json_decode($json); 
    $i = 1;

    while ($i <= 2) {
        $entrynumber = "entry" . $i;
        echo "name ----- " . $data->$entrynumber->name . "<br>";
        echo "age ------- " . $data->$entrynumber->age . "<br>";
        $i++;
    }

    // decrypted json - doesnt work!
    echo "<h3>Decrypted JSON doesnt work:</h3>";
    $data = json_decode($decrypted);
    $i = 1;

    while ($i <= 2) {
        $entrynumber = "entry" . $i;
        echo "name ----- " . $data->$entrynumber->name . "<br>";
        echo "age ------- " . $data->$entrynumber->age . "<br>";
        $i++;
    }
?>
```

If you paste that code into a php document you will see what I mean.

**Screenshot:**

[image]

Comment: "It doesn't work" is *never* a good error description. Please describe what goes wrong, what error messages you get, etc.

Comment: I did explain, see the php comments.

Comment: could you copy paste the HTML, instead of a browser screenshot? Maybe the decrypted json string has some HTML entities such as &quot;, or something

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Your encryption/decryption algorithm is adding padding to conform to the block-size. You should remove null-characters from the end, for example:

`rtrim($decrypted, "\0");`

Comment: Thank you also!  I've been trying to figure this out all morning.

Comment: Just a head's up, this *will* expose your application to padding oracle attacks. You're far better off using the PKCS7 padding strategy on the plaintext before encrypting, and stripping it off after.

Answer (score 3):

Did some troubleshooting and this is what I got:

URL Encode/decode is not the problem. String before encoding and after decoding are the same:

Before encoding:

```
string 'è?¡OùpU4ˆß•ý£ÉGÒô½åLqe 2w¨”—Ô¢§|MþWþxÎZ±8“Ñ”Ð©É“ ŽšÁkèíSòøÓ€¥ðÒ(³!§¬žIê\&' (length=96)
```

After decoding:

```
string 'è?¡OùpU4ˆß•ý£ÉGÒô½åLqe 2w¨”—Ô¢§|MþWþxÎZ±8“Ñ”Ð©É“ ŽšÁkèíSòøÓ€¥ðÒ(³!§¬žIê\&' (length=96)
```

The problem is in the encryption / decryption process.

Json string before encrypting:

```
string '{"entry1":{"name":"bob","age":"15"},"entry2":{"name":"bill","age":"50"}}' (length=72)
```

Json string after decrypting:

```
string '{"entry1":{"name":"bob","age":"15"},"entry2":{"name":"bill","age":"50"}}������������������������' (length=96)
```

See the extra garbage characters added to the end.

After decrypting if you do this to trim out the garbage characters, your json decodes fine:

```
json_decode(substr($decrypted,0,72));
```

I'm not very familiar with `mcrypt`, so hopefully someone can help you figure out why you're getting the additional characters at the end.