# I can't decode to json after decryption

Tags: php, json, encryption

I can't decode json with json_decode() function after decrypt an encrypted string

Here is my encrypt and decrypt code

```
    function encrypt($s, $key = "", $iv = "") {
            if (strlen($key) == 0)
                    $key = $this->default_key;
            if (strlen($iv) == 0)
                    $iv = $this->default_iv;
            $iv_utf = mb_convert_encoding($iv, 'UTF-8');
            return base64_encode(mcrypt_encrypt($this->mcrypt_cipher, $key, $s, $this->mcrypt_mode, $iv_utf));
    }

    function decrypt($s, $key = "", $iv = "") {
            if (strlen($key) == 0)
                    $key = $this->default_key;
            if (strlen($iv) == 0)
                    $iv = $this->default_iv;
            $iv_utf = mb_convert_encoding($iv, 'UTF-8');
            return mcrypt_decrypt($this->mcrypt_cipher, $key, base64_decode($s), $this->mcrypt_mode, $iv_utf);
    }
```

Decrypt output is looking well ( output is { "stage_index" : "0" } )
but I can't decode to json it's always return to NULL, I don't know why :(

Comment: What does your `json_decode()` call look like? Have you checked [`json_last_error()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.json-last-error.php)?

Comment: @rutter No I havn't checked 

and this is message after checked 
(JSON_ERROR_CTRL_CHAR) Unexpected control character found

Comment: Have you checked [this answer?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8429900/php-json-not-working-when-using-urldecode-and-mcrypt)
Might be useful.

Comment: @Tarnation Wow, Thank you, I found a solution (y).